# Fine tuning a UPDATE query on a table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have 2 tables table1 and table2 both having large amounts of data, Table1 has 5 million and Table2 has 80,000 records. I am running an update,

```
Update Table1 a
Set 
a.id1=(SELECT DISTINCT p.col21 
         FROM Table2 p 
         WHERE p.col21 = SUBSTR(a.id, 2, LENGTH(a.id));
```

The substr and distinct in the query are making it slow.

1. How can this query be re-written to speed up the process and
2. What columns do I need to index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be a merge

```
 merge into Table1 a
  using Table2 p 
  on (p.col21 = SUBSTR(a.id, 2, LENGTH(a.id))
  When matched then
     update set a.id1 = p.col21;
```

and a Function Based Index on `a.id`.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are dynamically calculating:

```
p.col21=SUBSTR(a.id,2,LENGTH(a.id))
```

This will take some substantial time and make it impossible to create an index. Did you consider actually creating a column with that value? This would allow you to index on it and make it much faster. If the id is static this seems like an easy win.

Comment: "make it impossible to create an index", not entirely true. You could create a function based index and it would be used. (http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/8i/function-based-indexes.php). You are right though that this is possibly where the problem lies.

Comment: the index on column `a.id` couldn't be used but an FBI can be created.

Comment: Thank you Ollie I did not know about that. It seems like this could solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

How many rows does your subquery return, and how many rows are you updating? With a large number of updates, indexes may not help you out at all.